# Issue with saving user information using django_registration

Tags: django, django-registration

I am using django_registration v0.8 and using the docs here: http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-registration/en/latest/index.html

I have successfully installed the app, and I am using the default backend for my registration purposes.

I have tested this and I can get the form to show up properly at '/accounts/register'

However, one problem is that if I try and break the form input (different password1 and password2 or improper username), no validation errors are being invoked.

The issue also, is that the username, email, and password data is not being stored in auth_user, and the activation email isn't being sent.

From the default backend doc, "During registration, a new instance of django.contrib.auth.models.User is created to represent the new account, with the is_active field set to False. An email is then sent to the email address of the account, containing a link the user must click to activate the account; at that point the is_active field is set to True, and the user may log in normally."

I believe this new instance of django.contrib.auth.models.User is not being created.

I have also included the necessary email settings:
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "Email"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "Password"
EMAIL_PORT = 587

Any help on getting this straight? I am pretty sure I am missing something simple, but been trying to figure it out without any progress. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the form is actually catching the error but you're just not seeing it. Do you have any code in your template that's checking for form errors? Something like the following could help you see if an error has occured:

```
   {% if form.errors %}
        <div class="lead">
            <h3 class="error">
                Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
            </h3>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Michael - Thanks for the tip! Including some code to catch the form errors will be helpful. In this case however, no errors are invoked. Even if I submit a blank form, it goes through and send me to the re-direct link. In one way, the right form class is being used, but in another way the errors defined in that form class are not being invoked.

Comment: Why don't you post your template code - specifically, the form.